# Spring Social - Organization with multiple users connected with single account

Tags: spring, spring-social

I am building an app that manages organizations and I am starting to use spring social. Each organization has several users that can manage all the details of it. The initial idea is that any user that connects the organization with any social account from the control panel should connect it for the entire organization. The problem I'm having is that from what I see spring social connections are related to a single user and not an organization and I was wondering how this should be done? Any ideas?

Thanks in advance

Comment: My experience was that OAuth worked great as long as you were only dealing with social accounts owned by individual humans. It stopped matching up well with the use cases when you get into situations where social accounts are owned/managed by multiple humans. I would love to hear if people have found good ways to address that mismatch.